# More than one type of user using devise gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

Im trying to create a site where there is a separate page for a teacher to login and a student to login (two separate forms on different pages). Im using the devise gem and thought so far the best way to do this is to generate 2 models using

```
rails generate devise Teacher
rails generate devise Student
```

then generating the views and editing them to take in different information as required. I'm new to ROR and was wondering if there is a better solution to this or a better way of doing this, or is this the optimal way of doing the task required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one model but have multiple roles (teacher, student, etc...) for it with  something like [rolify](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify). This will be a lot leaner and more flexible down the line than having distinct controllers, models and so on.